# Targetting a Bootstrap modal CSS class with specific ID

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[Demo](http://www.bootply.com/dfYmEMzxg9)

I need to change only the background of one of the Modals with specific ID `#firstModal` which I am using in Bootstrap 3 by using this CSS rule

```
  #firstModal.modal-backdrop  {
     background-color: green;  
     opacity: 1 !important;
     filter: Alpha(opacity=50);
}
```

and here is the modal

```
<div id="firstModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
            <h3 id="myModalLabel">First Modal</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>One fine body…</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TRY - [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/vUhpGS03pL)

**CSS:**

```
/* CSS used here will be applied after bootstrap.css */

#firstModal {
  background-color: green;  
  opacity: 1 !important;
  filter: Alpha(opacity=50);
}
```

Comment: Hi Mary Thanks for reply but I was looking for a solution to change the behind background of the Modal Content and thats why I was using the .modal-backdrop.